# jQuery only clicking once

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code I am only able to click on any of the following HTML elements the Loader Element in `<a></a>` is displaying from the second click its not showing anything. All works only for first time and its not working from second click. Can anyone have a look for me? Thanks.

```
<li><a id="OVERALL_VALUE" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setTopDeals('OVERALL_VALUE')" class="topdeal">Top Deals</a></li>
                    <li><a id="PRICE" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setTopDeals('PRICE')" class="price">Price</a></li>
                    <li><a id="QUALITY" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setTopDeals('QUALITY')" class="quality">Star Rating</a></li>


                    <li><a id="list" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list">List View</a></li>
                    <li><a id="grid" href="javascript:void(0)" class="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a id="map" href="javascript:void(0)" class="map">Map View</a></li>
```

Display loader

```
<a id="ajaxload_more3" style="display:none; width:200px; height:80px; border:1px solid #000; opacity:0.8; border-radius:10px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:25px; position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:1000; text-align:center; background-color:#997CE6;"><table align="center"><tr height="50"><td><img src="images/ajaxload.gif" height="50" width="50" /></td></tr><tr height="35"><td><span style="font-size:20px; color:#FFF;">Loading</span></td></tr></table></a>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#OVERALL_VALUE" ).click(function() {
          $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
          $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
        });
        $( "#PRICE" ).click(function() {
          $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
          $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
        });
        $( "#QUALITY" ).click(function() {
          $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
          $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
        });
        $( "#list" ).click(function() {
          $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
          $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
        });
        $( "#grid" ).click(function() {
          $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
          $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
        });
        $( "#map" ).click(function() {
          $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
          $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
        });
         </script>
```

Comment: If all you want is to show a "loading" message when an Ajax request is active, check out [.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) and [.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/).

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, you should first consider [Don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  All are doing the same operations then why a separate selector? Instead use `class`  or directly element selectors

```
 $( "li" ).on('click', 'a', function() {
          $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
          $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading DOM elements dynamically (AFTER LOADING the Javascript).. Click events are not bound to the new appended elements..

In such situations you have to use "On" or "Live" binding. Live binding is deprecated hence I would suggest you to use "on" binding...

Here is the working code snippet alternative for your Javascript.. Try it..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "body" ).on("click", "#OVERALL_VALUE", function() {
      $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
      $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
    });
   $( "body" ).on("click, "#PRICE", function() {
      $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
      $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
    });
    //CONVERT ALL THE ELEMENTS JUST LIKE THAT
     </script>
```

I hope this helps. thank you!

***BETTER APPROACH***

And as suggested by another member.. Don't repeat yourself..

Instead.. Convert your HTML in to this :

```
                 <li><a id="PRICE" class="ajaxLoadIt" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setTopDeals('PRICE')" class="price">Price</a></li>
                <li><a id="QUALITY" class="ajaxLoadIt" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setTopDeals('QUALITY')" class="quality">Star Rating</a></li>


                <li><a id="list" class="ajaxLoadIt" href="javascript:void(0)" class="list">List View</a></li>
                <li><a id="grid"class="ajaxLoadIt"  href="javascript:void(0)" class="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a id="map" class="ajaxLoadIt"" href="javascript:void(0)" class="map">Map View</a></li>
```

And the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "body" ).on("click", ".ajaxLoadIt", function() {
  $( "#ajaxload_more3" ).show("slow");
  $("#ajaxload_more3").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
});

//CONVERT ALL THE ELEMENTS JUST LIKE THAT
 </script>
```

Comment: `"document"` should be `document`

Comment: I tried your code and this works at http://jsfiddle.net/gBsZG/ but still doesn't work at www.ther8.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "#" instead of "javascript:void(0)" or else just remove the HREF attribute

Answer (score 0):

You don't see it anymore since at the end of the `fadeOut` function the DOM element's `display` is `none`. You should add your customised logic what to do after the fade out process has been completed